# Zend_Mail will not send bcc to sender address

Tags: zend-framework, email, zend-mail

I have a problem, when I want to send mail to a customer and also to the admins.

The problem is, that the customer receives the mail, but the bcc will not if the from = bcc. Is there any setting I have missed? 
**Could this be a server issue, or a Zend related one?**

Example code I use:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom( 'admin@example.com', 'Admin' )
->addTo( 'customer@anydomain.com', 'Customer' )
->setBodyText( 'Example' )
->addBcc('admin@example.com');

$mail->send();
```

The headers are (from $mail->getHeaders()):

```
array(3) {
  ["From"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(26) "Admin <admin@example.com>"
    ["append"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["To"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "Customer <customer@anydomain.com>"
    ["append"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["Bcc"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "admin@example.com"
    ["append"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
}
```

Comment: To begin with, you should quote your email addresses, i.e. `$mail->setFrom('admin@example.com')`, if it's not a typo in your question.

Comment: Sorry, it was just typo, the main question is why the admin is not receiveing the bcc mail if it was sent by him. I will correct the example.

Comment: Can you please see the header information and paste it here? That will help us investigate further. You can get mail-header by calling `$mail->getHeaders()` method.

Comment: @RakeshS I have updated the question with the headers info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled on this post while working on using `Zend_Mail` to send a bcc to the sender address  and found that for me the following does in fact work:

```
$fromName = 'admin';
$fromMail = 'sender@mail.com';

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
$mail->addBcc($fromMail);
```

Even though the bug report http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8723 as linked in RakeshS's post is still marked as unresolved. My Zend version is:

```
const VERSION = '1.11.12';
```

It would be interesting to learn whether the problem would also be solved for the original posters for the updated Zend framework, if they may happen to read this

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same behavior as you. The sender is not getting the message if the address is added as Bcc. So, it's likely to be a Zend Mail related issue (I don't think we have the same server configuration).

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug added to ZF which almost similar to this issue: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8723

BTW, you could also get BCC to work with the help of [Zend Mail Add Header method](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.5/en/zend.mail.additional-headers.html). Please try the following work-around:

```
$mail->addHeader('Bcc', 'admin@example.com');
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, I have tried, but the server gives a 500 error. Although it would be a good workaround, it seems to me that this is not working. Maybe there is a different way of injecting the header.

Comment: I have tried it like this: $mail->addHeader('bcc: admin@example.com');
But it will send the letter 2 times to the original recipient (customer).

Comment: If you are using this, then you shouldn't use `addBcc()` method. I hope you ain't using it.

Comment: It seems that this version is able to send the mail to the addresses correctly, but puts the header info into the mail body:

$mail->addHeader("Bcc: admin@example.com\r\n");

If I could correct this, then it would be perfect... :)

Comment: May be it thinks its something different, can you try this: `$mail->addHeader('bcc: admin@example.com', '', true);` and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

if you use only Bcc recipients without TO
read this

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-3509

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Please read the question first, there is a TO recipient in my example. The problem is when the FROM = BCC.